# How to backtrack in PROLOG

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I have the following PROLOG query and it's database.

```
r(X,Y), s(Y,Z), not(r(Y,X)), not(s(Y,Y).

r(a,b). r(a,c). r(b,a). r(a,d).
s(b,c). s(b,d). s(c,c). s(d,e).
```

How does PROLOG backtracks in this example? I figured it would be something like:

```
1-  Unifies X with 'a' and Y with 'b'

2-  Unifies Y with 'b' and Z with 'c'

3-  This goal means that there mustn't be any other clause in the database where 
   this happens: r(a,b) r(b,a). 
    My doubt lies here. Does prolog advance to the next goals or does it verify 
   the other r(X,Y) database clauses to check for a match and possibly invalidate 
   the solution?

    I guess that what Prolog does is the following:
   - Verifies the rest of the r(X,Y) clauses to check for a r(Y,X) match and if 
   there is one, then it backtracks to the 2nd step (s(Y,Z)). 
    This will obviously generate unnecessary tree branches which do not need to be 
   tested since the 1st goal is always the same.

4. Verifies if S(X,Y), X == Y. Backtracks to step 1 with new values (a & c) and so on.
```

Am I correct? If someone could draw a tree based on this problem I would really apreciate so I can fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the tracer to look at the proof tree (which some consider a bad practice, but it does help understand the execution model if you have difficulties with that). So there you go (replacing the `not/1` with `\+/1`):

```
?- trace(r/1), trace(s/1).
true.

[debug]  ?- r(X, Y), s(Y, Z), \+ r(Y, X), \+ s(Y, Y).
 T Call: (7) r(_G341, _G342)
 T Exit: (7) r(a, b)
 T Call: (7) s(b, _G345)
 T Exit: (7) s(b, c)
 T Call: (7) r(b, a)
 T Exit: (7) r(b, a)
 T Redo: (7) s(b, _G345)
 T Exit: (7) s(b, d)
 T Call: (7) r(b, a)
 T Exit: (7) r(b, a)
 T Redo: (7) r(_G341, _G342)
 T Exit: (7) r(a, c)
 T Call: (7) s(c, _G345)
 T Exit: (7) s(c, c)
 T Call: (7) r(c, a)
 T Fail: (7) r(c, a)
 T Call: (7) s(c, c)
 T Exit: (7) s(c, c)
 T Redo: (7) r(_G341, _G342)
 T Exit: (7) r(b, a)
 T Call: (7) s(a, _G345)
 T Fail: (7) s(a, _G345)
 T Redo: (7) r(_G341, _G342)
 T Exit: (7) r(a, d)
 T Call: (7) s(d, _G345)
 T Exit: (7) s(d, e)
 T Call: (7) r(d, a)
 T Fail: (7) r(d, a)
 T Call: (7) s(d, d)
 T Fail: (7) s(d, d)
X = a,
Y = d,
Z = e.
```

There is your proof tree. The `Redo` is where Prolog backtracks. When a call succeeds, the `\+` fails, and Prolog does a `Redo` after an `Exit`. When a goal fails, the `\+` succeeds after a `Fail`.

Comment: That was very useful to analyze the backtrack, ty!